# Piping Cat with Echo

Tags: unix

I am trying to understand how pipes work in Unix.

Say I have a textfile called a.txt with content.
If I do `'cat a.txt | echo'`, nothing will be outputted. 
I expected it to echo each line of a.txt.

On the otherhand, if I do `cat a.txt | grep 'd'`,
it will output all lines that start with 'd'.

My understanding is that cat outputs the contents of a.txt to stdout, then the pipe sends that output to the input of grep 'd', but grep takes a file name as input, so how is this working like it is (if grep is given non file inputs)?

Comment: `grep` takes a file name if you supply one as the second argument. If you don't, it reads its `stdin`. `echo` never reads `stdin` or any files for that matter. It only echoes its arguments.
The program that echos its input is `cat`. If you don't supply an argument to `cat`, it'll read `stdin`, thus `cat a.txt | cat` will do the same thing as `cat a.txt`

Comment: related: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to go into a text editor and wanted to save a piece of data in a file you could use

echo "somePassword" | cat > .myPasswordFile

You have piped the output of echo to cat and cat has saved it to a file

ls | cat > dirlist.txt
sends the output of the directory to a file called dirlist.txt

This is an example where echo pipes to the tee command to append something to the end of another file

echo "ServerName 127.0.0.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/conf-available/server-name.conf